# accessing delaycontenttouches property of uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Since uitableview inherits from uiscrollview, would i have access to the delayContentTouches property of UIScrollView from my table view controller?  I thought I could do something like the following, but it doesn't work(self is the UITableViewController):

```
self.view.delayContentTouches = YES;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of this property is YES, the scroll view delays handling the touch-down gesture until it can determine if scrolling is the intent. This value is YES by default. You'd better tell what do you want to do?